# MySql gives to me: ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT(8) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    second_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    administrator BOOLEAN default false,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE account(
    account_number INT(8) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    second_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    account_type INT(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (account_number),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(name) REFERENCES users(name)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I wanna make a relation for the "name" from the table account and "name" from the table users but it give me this error: ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

I searched in diferents pages but i didn't find the solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign key constraints should really be to primary keys.  Although you can have the constraints to unique and even non-unique keys (in MySQL), that is a bad practice in general.

So:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
    account_number INT(8) NOT NULL,
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    second_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    account_type INT(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (account_number),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Note that the name is not in the `account` table.  To get the name, you need to `JOIN` to `users`.

Comment: But i wana relacionate the "name" coluumn. Your code works, but i can't understand why can't my code work... Can you explain me the reason? Thank you bro!

Comment: @MiquelRosselloMelis . . . You *should* want the relation to the primary key, with the `id`.  Primary keys are the best columns to use for foreign eys.  You can't have a foreign key reference to a column that is not a key.